# SceneKit collision between camera and object misses initially

Tags: scenekit

I've got a camera node and a wall object node in my scene with assigned physics body properties. Basically when the camera is backing up through space and goes through a wall, I want to make the wall transparent so the camera can still see through it.

Camera physics bodies:

```
    let perspectiveCameraPhysicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: perspectiveCamera, options: nil)
    let perspectiveCameraphysicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: perspectiveCameraPhysicsShape)
    perspectiveCamera.physicsBody = perspectiveCameraphysicsBody
    perspectiveCamera.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 1
    perspectiveCamera.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 2
```

Wall nodes:

```
            let physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: node.geometry!, options: nil)
            let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: physicsShape)
            node.physicsBody = physicsBody
            node.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 2
            node.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 1
            node.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
```

My delegate is set appropriately, and here's the execution:

```
    func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
    // Check if the camera has collided with an object
    if contact.nodeA == scene.perspectiveCamera || contact.nodeB == scene.perspectiveCamera {
        let collidedObject = contact.nodeA == scene.perspectiveCamera ? contact.nodeB : contact.nodeA

        // Adjust the opacity of the collided object to make it lower
        collidedObject.opacity = 0.10
    }
}
```

So the only issue I'm having is intially the camera/wall is not triggering this delegate call. Meaning, I must back the camera up through the wall first, then only on the second collision (moving forward again) will this delegate method trigger.

After that it triggers fine on any collisions after (albeit at slightly strange timings, I'm suspecting it has something to do with the physics body sizes?), but the first collision always goes undetected. Thanks

Comment: Can shou share a scratch project demonstrating the issue, so I could have a look at it?